# <cfquery> not retrieving DATA

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

I am unable to retrieve any data from my cfquery. Same query when i run in sql developer i get the result.

Any reason why ?

Hi all, thanks for the responses. Sorry, it was my fault. 
It was a data issue. I was retrieving uncommited data from CF.

Comment: Can you paste some of your code?

Comment: Any number of reasons. Datasource in CF admin not set up correctly; Synonyms not matching; etc. You'll need to give us some more to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also build the query in CFEclipse, test it and then paste the query in your CFQuery tag.

Also check how you have put the query name in the CFoutput tag, so many times I've put #queryname# instead of queryname in cfoutput.

Comment: Hi it was a silly mistake i was doing. It was a DB issue. I Insered the data and without commiting the changes i was trying to retrieve it from my CF code. Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

Is the query actually being ran?

If you can turn debugging on, does the query show as being executed?

Also when you run the same query do you mean you copy/paste the query from the debugger into sql developer?

Perhaps the same values are not being included (if you are using variables in there)

Comment: Yeah, query executed and I tried the same query in sql developer (Though i have replaced the cf variables). 
What i think now is that might be a caching issue, Because the cfquery which i was executing was trying to retrieve the data from a table that was newly added. All the other queries that are working are fetching results from older tables. Can caching be a problem ?